# Concentrate two lists alternating python

Tags: python, list, python-zip

I want to combine two lists in an alternating way in Python.

```
list1 = ['A']
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

What I've tried:

```
combination = [x for y in zip(list1, list2) for x in y]
# Output: 
['A', 1]

# Expected output:
['A', 1, 'A', 2, 'A', 3, 'A', 4]
```

How can I combine these two lists and get the expected output? (Preferably list comprehension)

Comment: To clarify... What should the output be if *list1 = ['A', 'B']* ?

Comment: Then it should be ['A', 1, 'B', 2, 'A', 3, 'B', 4]

Comment: @cinnamon then don't you think that would be a better example to use in your question? Currently, 2 answers work for the question but fail with that detail...

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use itertools cycle function:

```
from itertools import cycle

list1 = ['A']
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

combination = [x for y in zip(cycle(list1), list2) for x in y]
```

This also works with

```
list1 = ['A', 'B']
```

Comment: Could also use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` which is basically `flatten`, rather than a list comprehension. Also OP if the input doesn't have to be a list, you can just use `itertools.repeat` to create an infinite iterator of a single item.

Comment: @Masklinn True but OP specifically wants to use a list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

`list1*len(list2)` will repeat the first list elements as many times as the length of the second list.

```py
combination = [x for y in zip(list1*len(list2), list2) for x in y]
```

---

```
['A', 1, 'A', 2, 'A', 3, 'A', 4]
```